# Why the default vertical alignment in table cell is not center but a bit higher?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

here is a minimal test code

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline 
地址 & 0ADH & 0AEH  \tabularnewline
\hline 
数据  &03H &09H  \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

And this gives the result like below:
[image: text in table cell]

It looks like the text(either Chinese text or English text) is a bit higher then expected(vertical centered), any ideas?

I build the code with TextLive 2015, and xelatex under Windows. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The default is not to align characters vertically by their centres, but to use the usual default alignment which is to align characters by their baselines.

You have chosen very non-typical content for English: all of your characters have zero depth. But most lines of English text have depth, as well as height. When you read these lines, you do not expect the web browser to centre the `y` relative to the `o` and the `u` in `you`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
  \hline
  All & things & stay\\\hline
\end{tabular}
on the baseline.
\end{document}
```

[image: baseline default alignment]

Comment: Hi, cfr, thanks for the explanation, indeed the default vertical alignment in the cell is based on the baseline, but for Chinese characters(they don't have chars with depths), all the contents are a bit higher, any ideas to solve this issue? I mean align characters vertically by their centres.

Comment: @ollydbg23 Ah. That's not what you asked ;). Have you tried `m{}`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried `|m{2.5cm}|m{2.5cm}|m{2.5cm}|`, but the result is the same as `|l|l|l|` in the vertical alignment.

Comment: I'm surprised that the support for Chinese doesn't make the required adjustments. I assume you're using Polyglossia or something like that?

Comment: Quote "Polyglossia"? No, I use purely Chinese language or English languages, what do you mean by "Polyglossia"?

Comment: @ollydbg23 Like `babel` but for XeTeX/LuaTeX and, therefore, a more likely choice for Chinese.

Comment: I did use XeLatex to build my test code, do you mean this engine does not support Chinese language quite well?

Comment: No, you're probably right. I expected Polyglossia to support Chinese, but it doesn't seem to do so.